# What does Spamd "Tell: Did nothing for (unknown):0 in 0.0 seconds" mean?

Tags: email-spam, spamassassin

I'm hooking spamd up to my email program, and when I use the "TELL" command to send it a known SPAM email, the log shows:

```
   spamd: Tell: Did nothing for (unknown):0 in 0.1 seconds, 13194 bytes
```

Is this normal?  Or am I screwing something up?

Answer (score 0):

There can be more than one issue with your setup if you're getting this message.

1. Since it says `unknown` instead of username, it appears that you are not passing a `User: <xyz>` header to spamd.
2. Try doing a TELL call after #1. If you still get the same message("Did nothing for", then use spamd with debug mode enabled (-D) if there was an issue in connecting to/opening your tokens DB.